# Add an extra form to all views

Tags: angularjs

In a scenario where I have multiple views with multiple controllers, I'd like to add the same login form to each and every one of them.

I have an index page which is the container for all the views, that has the link to toggle the modal login window

```
INDEX.HTML
<html>
   ....

   <body>
     ...

            <div class="menu">
               <a href="">login</a>
            </div>
            <div class="main" ng-view>


            </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

I would add the div with the modal window to the bottom of this page, but it wouldn't make it into the ng-view, so I was wondering if there was an elegant solution to have it added to all the views without having to replicate the code over every single view.
Otherwise the ugliest and simplest solution would be to ng-include the login form, into the html of every single view.

Answer (score 0):

With a scenario like this I would look into using angular UI router.

https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router